# IE dynamically created Iframe's onload function never called

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I am struggling with the issue that I am unable to attach any `onload` function to my dynamically created iframe. This happens only in IE, works in FF. Here is my code:

```
var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "legacy-hostpage.html?rnd=" + new Date().getTime());
ifrm.style.width = "100%";
ifrm.style.height = "400px";
ifrm.name = "legacy-frame";
ifrm.id = "IFRM-" + new Date().getTime();

ifrm.onload = function() {
  alert('onload onload');
};

wrapper.appendChild(ifrm);
```

I wish I could use jQuery in this project but I can't.. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use attachEvent function for IE.

```
  function myLoad() {
      alert( "onload onload" );
  }

  if ( window.addEventListener ) { 
      ifrm.addEventListener( "load", myLoad, false );
  }
  else if ( window.attachEvent ) { 
      ifrm.attachEvent( "onload", myLoad );
  }
  else {
      ifrm.onload = myLoad;
  }

  wrapper.appendChild( ifrm );
```

Above code should work in all browsers without problems.

Comment: If you want your event to fire reliably, see Remy's answer as well.

Comment: This is not working for me and others when loading PDFs. Another solution is to put your iframe in an iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412047/onload-event-for-dynamically-created-iframe-never-fires-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

You should add the onload callback before you set the src attribute.

Comment: That's correct. If the IFRAME loads fast (e.g. from cache or whatnot) your event handler may not fire otherwise.